# How to deploy ASP.NET MVC4 application with SQL Server CE to Azure website

Tags: deployment, sql-server-ce, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

I deployed a ASP.NET MVC4 app with SQL Server CE database, but I'm getting

> *Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request*

I am using VS2012 to publish this app to azure website. How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12419594/333730) and verify that it isn't the same problem

Comment: Thanks, I think it might be different problem, as I am using .net framework4.This is working fine locally. I think it might be missing some dependency files.But I am not sure which one is missing.

Comment: Have you turned on the debug settings in the web.config to get the ASP.NET Yellow Screen of Death with more specific error information? If so, I would suggest posting an image of that (scrubbing it of any private information of course)

Comment: After turning on debug settings, I get the message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Can you verify that this is the proper version of the assembly, as well as check to see that it is getting uploaded to [tag:azure-web-sites] you can browse the files that were uploaded to your site via ftp. I've seen issues in the past where a .gitignore was filtering out a bin directory which would cause this exact problem (and multiple others)

Comment: Thanks so much, SyntaxC4. This is resolved, it is due to the version mismatching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize and so an answer can get marked on this to help the next person that comes by.

When running into issues on [azure-web-sites](/questions/tagged/azure-web-sites) **FTP** is a handy debugging tool which enables you to:

- Verify that the `dll` exists in your **bin directory**

  - Sometimes the .gitignore file blocks directories from being checked in
- Verify that your `web.config` file has the proper version of the assembly configured

  - [NuGet](http://nuget.org) can help, but it's ultimately up to you to verify your dependencies

Comment: Another handy tool is WebMatrix 2 with which you can connect and have a remote view. It works nicely with WAWS btw.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article to follow on the subject: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=883
Unfortunately with VS 2013 Compact edition is not supported any more, so things are somewhat tricky.